# Generic sort method with Func<T, TH> delegate

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

What I'm trying to do is create a generic method that accepts a list of type `T` as well as a few search options (i.e. sort direction & sort field) then sorts the given list based on the search options.

I figure the issue might be related to the generic return type for the Func delegate I'm passing to the OrderBy method, but I'm not completely sure to be honest. Pretty stumped at the moment with this. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static class TableGenerationHelper
{
    public static IList<T> CreateReportObject<T>(IList<T> items, ISearchOptions searchOptions) where T : new()
    {
        Type sortFieldType = typeof(T).GetProperty(searchOptions.SortField)?.GetType();

        MethodInfo createMethod = typeof(TableGenerationHelper).GetMethod("CreateSortedList");
        MethodInfo methodRef = createMethod?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), sortFieldType);

        Object[] args = { items, searchOptions.SortField, searchOptions.SortDirection };

        results = (IList<T>)methodRef?.Invoke(null, args);

        return results;
    }

    public static IList<T> CreateSortedList<T, TH>(IList<T> items, String sortField, String sortDirection) where T : new()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(sortField);

        Func<T, TH> orderByFunc = x => (TH)propInfo?.PropertyType.GetRuntimeProperty(sortField)?.GetValue(x, null);

        return LoadListOrderedByDirection(items, orderByFunc, sortDirection);
    }

    public static IList<T> LoadListOrderedByDirection<T, TH>(IList<T> items, Func<T, TH> keySelector, String sortDirection)
    {
        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case "ASC":
                return items.OrderBy(keySelector).ToList();
            case "DESC":
                return items.OrderByDescending(keySelector).ToList();
            default:
                return items;
        }
    }
}
```

No exceptions are being thrown, but there is no sorting taking place. The original list is being returned in the order it was passed. Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT

My apologies for the clear lack of an actual question here. I honestly didn't realize it at the time of my post.

Thanks for the advice on null operators as well. This was giving me the impression the code was working as it should be, when it really should have been throwing an exception. This made debugging quite a frustrating process as it seemed there was nothing wrong while stepping through the code.

As StriplingWarrior mentioned in his response, I was using the `RuntimePropertyInfo` as opposed to the `PropertyInfo` in my lambda expression.

I will be sure to have an actual question the next time I post.

Comment: Start with: since there is a path in which the list is returned unsorted, check to see if you're on that path. If not, then the next thing to check is: does the key selector return sensible values? If the key selector, say, always selects the same value, then the list is already sorted by that key and will be returned unchanged.

Comment: the null conditional operators `?.` are probably causing this. something will be null, and methods are never called. use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Glad you found a solution; if you think the answer will help others, please accept the answer so that people know to not try to answer the question. If you think it will not help others, consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're eating a bunch of null values, which is causing you to miss some errors that you should probably be seeing exceptions for, and Eric Lippert is right that you really need to learn to step through your code to debug it.

You've got a couple of bugs here.

1. You're using `PropertyType` on `propInfo`, which gives you the type returned by the property, rather than the type of object the property is declared on. Then you're asking *that type* for the property with a given name (which doesn't make much sense to me, since you already have the PropertyInfo from calling GetProperty in the first place).
2. You're using `GetType()` on the result of `GetProperty`, which will always return the type of the runtime property information class, not the actual type of the property. You want to use `PropertyType` instead.

This seems to work correctly:

```
public static IList<T> CreateReportObject<T>(IList<T> items, ISearchOptions searchOptions) where T : new()
{
    Type sortFieldType = typeof(T).GetProperty(searchOptions.SortField).PropertyType;

    MethodInfo createMethod = typeof(TableGenerationHelper).GetMethod("CreateSortedList");
    MethodInfo methodRef = createMethod?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), sortFieldType);

    Object[] args = { items, searchOptions.SortField, searchOptions.SortDirection };

    var results = (IList<T>)methodRef?.Invoke(null, args);

    return results;
}

public static IList<T> CreateSortedList<T, TH>(IList<T> items, String sortField, String sortDirection) where T : new()
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(sortField);

    Func<T, TH> orderByFunc = x =>
    {
        return (TH)propInfo.GetValue(x, null);
    };

    return LoadListOrderedByDirection(items, orderByFunc, sortDirection);
}
```